# woocommerce api + React app: Can't not POST or PUT but can GET

Tags: reactjs, windows, xampp, woocommerce-rest-api

I am working on configuring my Woocommerce + React app and am running into a 401 unauthorized error when making a POST request. I am able to successfully retrieve data with a GET request, but am struggling with POSTs.

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzhSx.png)

This is my first project with Woocommerce and React and I am working on localhost using XAMPP to run WordPress. I'm using Windows 11 as my operating system. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If more information or screenshots are needed, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes that I've thought of:

1. Your XAMPP is running on HTTP and not HTTPS.
   If this is the case, then you should be able to follow the instructions in the documentation for doing HTTP "one-legged" authentication: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#authentication-over-http
2. You're using a read-only API key instead of a read/write API key. (unlikely, but worth checking)

Comment: hello and thanks for answering, indeed I have localhost running with http, I did some research on the HTTP authentication of the woocommerce api and applied a "solution" that didn't really work but what I don't know is if I'm doing things right or not:

I installed oauth-1.0a: To generate the OAuth 1.0a signature - I installed axios: To make the HTTP requests.

i get the same 401 error, maybe i missed some step or forgot something :/ i can't get it to work

i try to put screenshots of my code but here i can't

Comment: i added a new comment with link screenshots, please if someone could help me